# How to solve linking problems in Xcode with LLVMSwift?

Tags: swift, xcode, linker, llvm

I am attempting to use [LLVMSwift](https://github.com/llvm-swift/LLVMSwift#installation-without-swift-package-manager) in a command line project in Xcode (MacOS, Swift).  I followed the instructions for using Swift Package Manager and have added it as a dependency to the project.

It is giving a linking error when I try to build the project.  This is the first part:

```
ld: Undefined symbols:
 std::__1::basic_stringbuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>>::str() const, referenced from:
     llvm::NVPTXRegisterInfo::getName(unsigned int) const in libLLVMNVPTXCodeGen.a[3](NVPTXAsmPrinter.cpp.o)
     llvm::NVPTXTargetLowering::getPrototype(llvm::DataLayout const&, llvm::Type*, std::__1::vector<llvm::TargetLoweringBase::ArgListEntry, std::__1::allocator<llvm::TargetLoweringBase::ArgListEntry>> const&, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<llvm::ISD::OutputArg> const&, llvm::MaybeAlign, llvm::CallBase const&) const in libLLVMNVPTXCodeGen.a[8](NVPTXISelLowering.cpp.o)
     (anonymous namespace)::AVRAsmParser::validateTargetOperandClass(llvm::MCParsedAsmOperand&, unsigned int) in libLLVMAVRAsmParser.a[2](AVRAsmParser.cpp.o)
     (anonymous namespace)::InstrOrderFile::run(llvm::Module&) in libLLVMInstrumentation.a[11](InstrOrderFile.cpp.o)
     getStatString(char const*, int, int, char const*, bool) in libLLVMTransformUtils.a[31](ImportedFunctionsInliningStatistics.cpp.o)
```

Most other problems with LLVMSwift I have found while looking around are resolved by updating the PATH or rerunning `utils/make-pkgconfig.swift`, but neither of those worked for me.  I can run `llvm-config` from the terminal and I think that means it is in my PATH.  The LLVMSwift package can be built if `cd` to it and run `swift build`, but the project with it as a dependency will not build.

There's a reference to this exact problem on the [LLVM GitHub](https://github.com/llvm-swift/LLVMSwift/issues/240), but no solution.  That issue mentions this is "being due to gcc compiling included libs with stdlib and apple clang not".  I looked into this and found solutions of adding many different flags to "Other Linker Flags" in Xcode and changing some other related entries, but got no results with those.  Any ideas?